# 'TypeError: zmq.zmqVersion is not a function' received when including ZeroMQ JS binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, zeromq

I'm attempting to create a react app that subscribes to an IPC socket from JavaScript code. I use `npx create-react-app`.

I've opted to use the npm [`zeromq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeromq) install. However, I get the error:

`TypeError: zmq.zmqVersion is not a function`

The only steps for installation I take are:

```
npx create-react-app myproj
cd myproj
npm install zeromq
```

I've made attempts to ignore the package at the webpack level. Specifically, in `project/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` I've tried to add the following with no luck:

```
// ... 
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  // ...
  externals : {
    'zeromq' : 'zeromq'
  }
// ...
```

Ideally, I'd like to simply call import the library like it is described in the link:

`var zmq = require('zeromq');`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use zmq in ReactJs for reasons stated here : https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/issues/150

Try using the alternative: https://github.com/zeromq/JSMQ

Answer (score 0):

Try node 9 instead of 10.
And install latest ZMQ after:

```
nvm install 9
npm install zeromq@5
```